# Assigning data examples importance without repetition in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Given the following setup of a dataset:

```
tweet, number of retweets, genre
```

I want to build a softmax classifier that predicts the tweet genre(s).
I am struggling to find a way to assign sample importance to keras WITHOUT repeating the data (tweets).

For example: tweet #1 is retweet 1000 times for genre 1 and 3. tweet #2 is retweeted 100 for genre 1 and 4. How to incorporate the importance of tweet #1 to genre 1 and 3 without repeating the tweet itself 1000 times in the training data ?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(LSTM_SIZE)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(GENRES_LIST)+1,activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax))

m = tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=1)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=[m])


model.fit(train_data, epochs=50, validation_data=test_data,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.fit()`, I think duplicating your data is the only way to achieve what you want.

Alternatively, you can consider writing your own batcher with `.train_on_batch()` and `.test_on_batch()`. That way, you can control what you feed to the model.

A simple call to `numpy.random.choice()` with the parameter `p` should do what you want (inside your batcher):

Sources:

- https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `sample_weight` matrix and pass it to the `.fit` function. So lets assume you have 2 samples of tweets and each sample has its number of retweets (as you described). All you need is to create a 1-D array of weights for each of those samples (1:1 mapping). You can either enter the integer value or normalize the weights to values between 0 and 1.
Your data will look like this:

```
X_train = [tweet1, tweet2]
y_train = [[1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1]] # one-hot encoding
my_sample_weight = [1000,100]
model.fit(train_data, epochs=50, validation_data=test_data, sample_weight=my_sample_weight, verbose=1)
```